# Prove for a continuously differentiable map $\|f(x)- f(y) - f'(a)(x-y)\| \leq \varepsilon \|x - y\|$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to proof that if $f(x):\mathbb{R^m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ is continuously differentiable map, then $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists U(a) \subset \mathbb{R^m}$ - neighborhood, that $\forall x, y \in U(a)$ $$\|f(x)- f(y) - f'(a)(x-y)\| \leq \varepsilon \|x - y\|$$
The lecturer said that it could be proved just by subtracting definitions of differentiable functions:
$$f(x)- f(a) = f'(a)(x-a) + o(\|x-a\|)$$
$$f(y)- f(a) = f'(a)(y-a) + o(\|y-a\|)$$
where $f'(a)$ is Jacobian matrix. Then subtracting gives:
$$|f(x)- f(y) - f'(a)(x-y)| = |o(\|x-a\|) - o(\|y-a\|)|$$

I can't find a technical way to go further and prove that.We can choose $U(a)$ such that both $|o(\|x-a\|)|\leq \varepsilon\|x-a\|$ and $|o(\|y-a\|)| \leq \varepsilon\|y-a\|$. But as the triangle inequality works in a different way:$$|o(x-a)| - |o(y-a)|\leq |o(x-a)- o(y-a)|$$
here is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$||f(x)- f(y) - f'(y)(x-y)|| = o(||x-y||)$$
$$||f(x)- f(y) - (f'(y)-f'(a)+f'(a))(x-y)|| = o(||x-y||)$$
$$||f(x)- f(y) - f'(a)(x-y)|| \leq o(||x-y||) + ||f'(y)-f'(a)|| ||x-y||$$
$$||f(x)- f(y) - f'(a)(x-y)|| \leq \epsilon ||x-y|| + ||f'(y)-f'(a)|| ||x-y||$$

Since $f'$ is continuous, we have $||f'(y)-f'(a)|| \leq \epsilon$ by choosing a neighborhood based on continuity of $f'$

$$||f(x)- f(y) - f'(a)(x-y)|| = 2\epsilon||x-y||$$